# Saving physionet data in a PostgreSql using SQLAlchemy with FastApi

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I downloaded some data from PhysioNet and am attempting to construct a PostgreSQL database with it. I've defined my main app file, which contains a router called data_router to load data and save it into my database. I have also defined my dataModel and established the connection to the database. However, I am still encountering the "A string literal cannot contain NUL (0x00) characters" error when attempting to insert data into the PostgreSQL database. Can someone help me to solve this please? Thanks. You find bellow the data saving function :

```
def save_db(db: Session, tab_data):
try:
    for index, row in tab_data.iterrows():
        print(f"Processing row {index}: {row}")
        ecg_record_list = row['ecg_record'].tolist() if isinstance(row['ecg_record'], np.ndarray) else row['ecg_record']
        r_peaks_list = row['r_peaks'].tolist() if isinstance(row['r_peaks'], np.ndarray) else row['r_peaks']

        data_model = EcgDataModel(
            file_name=row['file_name'],
            fs=row['fs'],
            ecg_record=ecg_record_list,
            r_peaks=r_peaks_list,
            r_peaks_annotation=row['r_peaks_annotation'],
            ecg_annotation=row['ecg_annotation']
        )
        db.add(data_model)
        db.flush()
    db.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error from saving function: {e}")
```

Comment: If you're trying to solve binary data, use `LargeBinary` as the field type, not `String` or similar data types. Remember to recreate your tables after changing the field type.